# Get choices display value using enum as choices

Tags: django

I have a Django model in which I'm using the choices parameter. For the choices, I'm using a Python Enum. Now I want to display the choices display value in a template. I know there's `.get_fieldname_display` but it just returns the key instead of the display value in this case.

**Model:**

```
class LocalTitle(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=[(tag, tag.value) for tag in LocalTitleCodes])
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**Enum:**

```
class LocalTitleCodes(Enum):
     title_00 = 'Japanese'
     title_01 = 'English'
     title_02 = 'French'
```

So in my case, if I do `title.get_type_display` in my template it returns `title_00` and not `Japanese`. How can I get the display value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is more that `tag` does *not* map to `title__00`, but to a `LocalTitleCodes` object.

You should use:

```
class LocalTitle(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        choices=[(tag.name, tag.value) for tag in LocalTitleCodes]
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Since Django thus could not find a the corresponding value, it fallsback on the value stored in the database.

Since:

```
>>> [(tag, tag.value) for tag in LocalTitleCodes]
[(<LocalTitleCodes.title_00: 'Japanese'>, 'Japanese'), (<LocalTitleCodes.title_01: 'English'>, 'English'), (<LocalTitleCodes.title_02: 'French'>, 'French')]
>>> [(tag.name, tag.value) for tag in LocalTitleCodes]
[('title_00', 'Japanese'), ('title_01', 'English'), ('title_02', 'French')]
```

Comment: Wow, haha! How did I never notice that? *facepalm* Works like a charm. StackOverflow says I can't accept your answer yet, but I will in '10 minutes'. Many thanks mate! :)

Comment: For Django3.0+, use `models.TextChoices`

Answer (score 3):

```
class LocalTitle(models.Model):
    LOCALCODES = (
     ('title_00' , 'Japanese')
     ('title_01' ,'English')
     ('title_02' , 'French')
)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=LOCALCODES)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Or you can give your choice like this.