# Derive a Django 3.0 Choices class from existing Enum?

Tags: python, django, django-models, enums

Django 3 brought a new way to define field choides: [Field.choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices).
This brings some adavantages, e.g. enforces uniqueness and allows supplying human readable tags.

Unfortunately, I can't find a clean way to define the choices in a non-django module, so that these choices can be imported from non-django applications. Concretely:

- in my django app, I might have a shape that has colors.
- these color choices are to be used in my django model, but also in other non-django packages that need to know all valid choices (e.g. analysis)

Therefore I want to define these colors as stand-alone class in exactly one place, e.g.:

```
class ShapeColor(Enum):
    BLUE = 1
    GREEN = 2
    RED = 3
```

In the past I imported this Enum 'ShapeColor' anywhere I needed it. But I have not found a clean way to translate this Enum into the new models.IntegerChoices class.
I tried to inherit from my Enum:

```py
class ColorChoices(models.IntegerChoices, ShapeColors):
    pass
```

But of course this gives a TypeError("Cannot extend enumerations").

It would be great if anyone had a suggestion on how to cleanly derive a django choice enum from an existing Enum or similar construct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53129963/208880

Comment: @EthanFurman It is not a duplicate. As the user states he is using Django 2.1 and therefore not the models.Choices class (new in Django 3) I am talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging into the Django code a bit, it turns out that `Choices`, `IntegerChoices`, and `TextChoices` are all Django's versions of the basic `Enum` data type.  So, assuming feasibility, the easiest thing to do would be to create `ShapeColor` as a `models.IntegerChoices` directly.  If that's not feasible (maybe Django is not available where your other tools are running), then the next best thing would be to create `ColorChoices` from `ShapeColor`:

```
ColorChoices = model.IntegerChoices(
        'ColorChoices',
        [(m.name, m.value) for m in ShapeColor],
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I went down the same road as you (into the Django code), but hoped there would be a more 'Django' way of doing it. But ok, this seems to be the best solution for now. If someone comes up with another idea in the future (maybe django adds a feature), please do comment!